# Media queries working on different widths than I said in style.css file

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have defined media query in my .css file:

```
    @media (max-width: 1076px) {
     .menu li{
        width: 168px;
     }
}
```

But when I'm resizing the window 'li' element starts having width of 168px when the window's size is max 970px. 
I also have a line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in my .html document. What's may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1076px) {
 .menu li{
    width: 168px;
 }
}
```

1. You forgot to close the curly bracket (`}`).
2. `max` means that it'll affect if width smaller 1976px. If I understood you correctly, you need the opposite - `min`.

Comment: But your code works for 1076+, I wanted 1076px and less.

Comment: I had curly bracket but I paste incorrectly. You understood incorrectly - I'd like to have effect on width smaller than 1076px. Media query starts working from much less than 1076px and I don't know why.

Comment: @user3516973 can you give me URL to your website where I'll be able to see the error?

Comment: I've got in on a localhost so here's a link to dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rckh64717j0dgwc/example.rar

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete cache and other browser data. Now it works for me. (I'm learning how to build wordpress sites and themes. This is a random theme I saw and want to build it from scratch :) )